# Source model "mttheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_source_block_proportions" not found for attribute mtmenu_proportions_right

Tags: magento-1.9

Please help me as i am new baby in Magento world. While accessing category from admin panel i got this error. 
Source model "mttheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_source_block_proportions" not found for attribute mtmenu_proportions_right
I searched lot but no result found.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE source_model like" mttheme% "

Find out with this template mttheme relevant records and then delete it